# How to detect debug/release in visual studio pre/post-build command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-2.0, pre-build-event, post-build-event

How can I detect **Debug** or **Release** mode from command line *pre-build* or *post-build* window?

I tested the code below, it works in code text window. 
Can it be convert to command line code?
If can, how to do it, thanks.

```
bool debugging = false;
#if DEBUG
    debugging = true;
    // do something like to move ../debug/bin/ to somewhere.
#else
    debugging = false;
    // do something like to move ../debug/bin/ to somewhere.
#endif

Console.WriteLine(debugging);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the value of the `$(ConfigurationName)` variable.

It is different to what you used in your code sample. `#if DEBUG` is a conditional compilation directive which depends upon whether `DEBUG` has been defined as a symbol or not. The `ConfigurationName` variable depends upon what *build configuration* you have specified (which is independent of the conditional compilation symbols).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo **** Visual Studio PREBUILD... **** 
echo **** Remember these are running from command line, aka BATCH commands 
echo **** watch out (include) single space after the conditional (and other ridiculous traps and pitfalls)
echo **** so I HIGHLY recommend getting out of BATCH and into Powershell as soon as possible.  Make prebuild a one-liner and then put additional code in your powershell... (you will thank me later)
echo **** Read more about why I'd rather claw my eyes out than program in BATCH here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_if_else_statement.htm

if "Debug" == $(ConfigurationName) (
  echo OPTIONALLY just pass in the Configuration name and do all the logic and checking INSIDE the powershell.  Seriously, it is way better.
  powershell .\DevBox.Prebuild.ps1 -Config:$(ConfigurationName)
)

echo *** Much better to just check for Debug INSIDE the powershell
powershell .\DevBox.Prebuild.ps1 -Config:$(ConfigurationName)
```

### Edit:

also see this answer for including powershell named parameters and solving the problem with spaces and escaping in (ProjectDir).
[How to escape spaces the parameters to a PS script running in VS post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205117/how-to-escape-spaces-the-parameters-to-a-ps-script-running-in-vs-post-build-even/73409081#73409081)